# Flash video capture

Tags: flash, streaming-flv-video

is there anyway to save the following flash video locally, perhaps by streaming it directly to drive? I primarily use Python, but any method would do.

http://www.cbc.ca/video/swf/UberPlayer.swf?state=embed&RSI=cbc-production&clipId=1354327087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should search for means for saving RTMP streams. It seems that saving RTMP streams will violate Adobe license.

Comment: ..thats waht i was afraid of.